# How to integrate the link embedded in custome HTML(using <a></a>) to breadcrums?

Tags: breadcrumbs

`Home >>`

On the Home page I have created a div and inserted some text there and  one of word I have added in Text area using CKeditor is ***Link to page-1***, so if i click that link it leads to me to page-1, so breadcrumb shows,

`Home >> page-1`

Now in the text area(body) of page 1 I have added another word ***Link to Page-2***, page-2 is a page created using the **views**. so after clicking this second link breadcrumbs shows,

`Home >> page-2`

But I want `Home >> page-1 >> page-2` which is the sequence in which I arrived on that page

although I have added this all links in the Body of text area using `<a></a>`, what I can do so breadcrumbs read this and make in the sequence as I want, In short how can we customize the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 1):

you can either extend the breadcrumb array with your link in your theme with [theme_breadcrumb](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7)  (further information [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/64067)) or [drupal_set_breadcrumb](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_set_breadcrumb/7) in your module, or use one of the many [modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/533448) around breadcrumb. maybe [custom breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) fits your needs.

you can extend the breadcrumb array with html, like:

```
$breadcrumb[] = l(t('My first page'), 'node/x');
```

or push it to the second postion with [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php), like:

```
array_splice($breadcrumb, 2, 0, l(t('My first page'), 'node/x'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider using a module for your breadcrumbs, such as:

#### [Path Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs)

> This module is a solution for all problems with the breadcrumbs on
>   your site!
>
> Path Breadcrumbs module helps you to create breadcrumbs for any page
>   with any selection rules and load any entity from the URL!

Here is a nice [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RebulQsp9s)

**or my personal favourite:**

#### [Crumbs, the Breadcrumbs suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/crumbs)

> Crumbs calculates breadcrumbs for your site. It does so by finding the
>   parent of the current page, then the parent of the parent, etc, until
>   it arrives at the home page.
>
> Crumbs comes with a bunch of built-in plugins, that can be
>   individually enabled, disabled and prioritized, and some of which
>   provide further configuration options.

**FYI: To access the config you need to go to** www.yourdomain.com/admin/structure/crumbs